# Difference between two versions of Aruch Hashulchan

Tags: product-recommendation, aruch-hashulchan

To the best of my knowledge, there are two prints of the Aruch Hashulchan with the psak of the Mishna Berura on the bottom. Does anyone know the difference between them?

1. [Oz VeHadar 9 volume](https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F---%D7%A2%D7%95%22%D7%94-%D7%98%22%D7%9B)
2. [Oz VeHadar 11 volume](https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F---%D7%A2%22%D7%A4-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94---%D7%99%22%D7%90-%D7%9B%D7%A8%27---%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%9F)

Comment: For what it's worth, the Oz Vehadar Aruch Hashulchan with Mishnah Berurah that I have is 13 volumes. No idea what the differences are.

Comment: @Salmononius2L when you look at your copy, is it closer to the description of the 9 vol or the 11 vol that Alex gives in his answer?

Comment: The 11 and 13 volume sets say published by Oz veHadar. The 9 volume set says Buchman. At least, the 9 volume set in the first link doesn't say Oz veHadar, it says Buchman. (I own a set with that cover.) So the 13 volume set must be closer to the 11 vol than an edition by a different publisher. I wonder if it's identical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There appear to be several differences between the two sets. Most obviously, one has 9 volumes while the other has 11 volumes.

- The 9 volume set appears to cover slightly more ground per page
  (which explains why it is smaller). For example, on the first page of
  Orach Chaim the 9 volume set already starts סעיף ו
  while the 11 volume set still needs the first couple of lines on the
  next page to finish סעיף ה.
- The 9 volume set prints the Hakdama (Introduction) before Orach Chaim (i.e. in the very first volume), while the 11 volume set prints the Hakdama before Choshen Mishpat (i.e. the beginning of the tenth volume) because the author actually started from Choshen Mishpat so originally that's where the Hakdama was.
- The 9 volume set has much more punctuation than the 11 volume set. There are many commas, quotation marks, periods, etc. in the former while the latter has virtually nothing (beyond markers for the end of each סעיף.)
- The 9 volume set has small letters on the side indicating which סעיף
  in Shulchan Aruch the סעיף in Aruch Hashulchan corresponds to (when
  applicable). The 11 volume set does not have this.
- Both sets have the additional parts on Hilchot Nedarim; the 9 volume set has it in the order of where it belongs in Yoreh Deiah, while the 11 volume set prints it in a separate volume at the end of Yoreh Deiah. This additional volume also has the author's derashot, which are at the end of Yoreh Deah in the 9 volume set.
- The sets cite the Mishnah Berurah's rulings slightly differently. For example, in the very first ruling cited the 9 volume set has:

> ובכלל זנות הוא מי שהוא רודף אחר תאוות העולם מבלי שיכוון בהם כלל לכוונה
>   טובה  כלומר שלא יעשה אותם כדי שיעמוד בריא ויוכל להשתדל בעבודת בוראו רק
>   כוונתו תמיד להרבות תענוגים גדולים לנפשו

while the 11 volume set has:

> ובכלל זנות הוא מי שהוא רודף אחר תאוות העולם מבלי שיכוון בהם שיהיה בריא
>   ויוכל להשתדל לעבודת בוראו רק כוונתו להרבות תענוגים לנפשו